# How to get folder size in the google drive using Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

In Android app, is it possibale to get the folder size in the google drive using the Drive API when I have the folder ID (driveId)? I tried:

```
driveId.getSize();
```

It dosn't work? any suggestion please?

Comment: as was implied, this feature is not supported yet so you have to do the manual process

Comment: Ok, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to recursively descend into the folder and add up the sizes.

Comment: Thanks for reply, any example?

Comment: @pinoyyid Take a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563371/non-latin-symbols-in-setqquery-in-google-drive-api-v2/45580271?noredirect=1#comment78124748_45580271) please...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Google App Script to achieve that.
https://github.com/zpf7879/GoogleAppScript/blob/main/README.md