# Non latin symbols in setQ(query) in Google Drive API V2

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, drive

I have Google Drive with two folders in the root - with latin and non latin (cyrillic) names:

[image]

When I search the Google Drive root with a

```
String query = "'root' in parents and title='Archive' and trashed=false"; 
drive.files().list().setQ(query).execute()
```

it gives me a metadata of `Archive` folder as on picture below:

[image]

But if I change query string to `'root' in parents and title='Архив' and trashed=false` (with Cyrillic folder name) it gives me nothing:

[image]

I am using **V2** of Google Drive API by means of following libs:

```
com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev154-1.18.0-rc
com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc
com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.18.0-rc
com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.18.0-rc
com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.18.0-rc
```

Is it a bug or should I use some encoding for non latin characters in the searched name? If last where does Google mention it in their docs!?

**UPDATE FOR V3**
The problem remains. Checked against following libs:

```
com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev80-1.22.0
com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0
com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0
com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0
com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.22.0
```

**SECOND UPDATE:** Some research with [API Explorer V2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) shows that the problem is in Russian capital letters. If there is atleast one capital letter in folder name: `'root' in parents and title='папкА' and trashed=false` a query with such folder name gives nothing:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "etag": "\"iqKjQ5Hr8wRO8SSHNW8KBrJOqxI/skD00QgZZ0FB6U5ufzrrxrFjqyA\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='root'+in+parents+and+title%3D'%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%90'+and+trashed%3Dfalse",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "items": []
}
```

If capital letters are absent in folder name: `'root' in parents and title='папки' and trashed=false` query returns correct json with folder metadata. The same is for **V3**. **Therefore the problem is in Drive server**.

**THIRD UPDATE:** Query `'root' in parents and title contains 'папкА' and trashed=false` returns a correct answer!

Comment: @noogui Do you mean to avoid of using non latin characters in folder names!?

Comment: If items with non latin characters are shown when you ask `drive.files().get(folderId).execute()` why should we avoid to find them with almost the same query `drive.files().list().setQ(query).execute()`? I suppose Google should fix this issue.

Comment: I mean - If items with non latin characters are shown when you ask `drive.files().list().setQ("'root' in parents and trashed=false").execute()` why should we avoid to find them with almost the same query `drive.files().list().setQ("'root' in parents and title='Архив' and trashed=false").execute()`? It looks unreasonable.I suppose Google should fix this issue.

Comment: I suggest start by deciding if this is a library issue or a Google Drive issue, So try getting this working using raw http calls using curl, ie. ignore the library, With raw http you can at least control the character set http headers to experiment. Once you have it working with curl, then figure out how to make the library behave the same way. You might even have to patch the library or submit a PR.

Comment: As I understand  **noogui** have made curl in the answer below and it works. I think it is a library issue.

Comment: try it yourself

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I've tried latin symbols in [Drive API version 3 Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) and I think it works.

So I have this folder named "**ɞʚᵷ**" which I hope is a Latin symbol and did a query.

```
name contains 'ɞʚᵷ' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

It works!

response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "0Bzgk4zccNwI7TFhPLUpGdmlmVVE",
   "name": "ɞʚᵷ",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
  }
 ]
}
```

**Updated**:
I've tried naming my folder in Russian like the one you're using - "Архив", and I had the same result, empty results. I think this is Drive's limitation. Kindly use English alphabet to ensure that the query always works.

Comment: Can you try `name='ɞʚᵷ' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`against V3?

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer if nobody suggest a solution for V2. Can you show libraries set to use V3 with Gradle in AS?

Comment: AS as in apps script? it is recommended that you use Drive V3.

Comment: AS - Android Studio.

Comment: Well there's the [Android REST Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) and the dedicated [Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)

Comment: The same problem on V3 if you use Google Drive SDK on Android.

Comment: Can you just try my query in your code? If it works, maybe your query statement is amiss : )

Comment: I did it on V3. When I use `drive.files().list().setQ("name='Archive' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute()` all is OK. When I change it to `drive.files().list().setQ("name='Архив' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute()` it gives nothing...

Comment: I actually tried your Russian alphabet as name of my folder, it doesnt work. This maybe the Drive's limiation as of now. Please use English.

Comment: Can you check `ɞʚᵷ` again with one capital letter? See my **SECOND UPDATE**.

Comment: It works with the "Aɞʚᵷ", I think Drive API doesnt support Russian

Comment: From which alphabet your "A" is? It should not be from Latin to catch a bug. I don't think it does not support Russian because it definitely supports Russian lowercase letters.